# Remove capital letter (at least 2 characters) from string in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, regex

I have some sample data below and would like to remove all capital letter which at least 2 characters or can say double capital letter.

```
HON MANI no St.Chom Chao Trapeang Thloeng Chaom Chau Dangkao 
LAY NA 35 st 70 Phum10 Boeng Salang Tuol Kouk Phnom Penh 
OK KEMEUN Ek Phnom , Battam Bang
CY VANN Rukkhak Kiri ,Battam Bang
LENG EUN , Korng Pisei , Kampong Speu
SEK HONG , Phnom Sruoch , Kampong Speu
```

I want to get result as below without Name

```
no St.Chom Chao Trapeang Thloeng Chaom Chau Dangkao 
35 st 70 Phum10 Boeng Salang Tuol Kouk Phnom Penh 
Ek Phnom , Battam Bang
Rukkhak Kiri ,Battam Bang
,Korng Pisei , Kampong Speu
, Phnom Sruoch , Kampong Speu
```

Any idea please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this

```
; with data as
(
    select  line = 'HON MANI no St.Chom Chao Trapeang Thloeng Chaom Chau Dangkao'   union all 
    select  line = 'LAY NA 35 st 70 Phum10 Boeng Salang Tuol Kouk Phnom Penh '  union all
    select  line = 'OK KEMEUN Ek Phnom , Battam Bang'   union all
    select  line = 'CY VANN Rukkhak Kiri ,Battam Bang'  union all
    select  line = 'LENG EUN , Korng Pisei , Kampong Speu'  union all
    select  line = 'SEK HONG , Phnom Sruoch , Kampong Speu'
)
select  *,
        result = case   when    first_two_word = upper(first_two_word) 
                 then   replace(line, first_two_word, '')
                 else   line 
                 end 
from    data
        cross apply
        (
            select  first_two_word = left(line, charindex(' ', line, charindex(' ', line) + 1))
        ) w
```

Comment: do always the capital letters come in the beginning of the data? I mean does this answer works even if capital letter exists in the middle of the data?

Comment: Nope. It won't. It is only for first 2 word only

Comment: @FLICKER this case the capital letters always in the beginning of data, so this script is worked just fine. anyway for general case if you could script it to work with capital letters beginning at any then it is much appreciated.

Comment: do you have such requirement ?

Comment: @Squirrel yeah I do.

Comment: can you post such example ?

Answer (score 1):

you can obtain the result by creating a scalar valued function

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.getLowerCaseString(@String VARCHAR(300))
RETURNS VARCHAR(300)
AS
BEGIN

WHILE(PATINDEX('%[ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ][ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ]%',LTRIM(@String) COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS )>0)
BEGIN
    SET @String = STUFF(@String,PATINDEX('%[ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ][ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ]%',LTRIM(@String) COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS ) ,CHARINDEX(' ',LTRIM(@String)),'')   
END

RETURN @String
END
GO
```

Call the function like

```
 SELECT 
    dbo.getLowerCaseString(StringColumn)
 FROM
  YourTable
```

Comment: this function is also worked, but a little slow..~100K data.